# Another template in the future?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

With this framework being predominantly a Microsoft framework I was wondering if in the future it would be worthwhile building a template for  [Razor Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio)?

Not looked into it too much myself but I would imagine there would be some effort involved to take the current Abp Controller logic into some sort of an Abp Page base class.

Just asking for people personal opinion - no right or wrong here :-)

Comment: "It's not possible to add action filters to razor pages yet" - [#2464](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2464)

Comment: i did not realize it's actually already on the backlog - good news as 2.1 is not far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a big effort for us to convert all templates (especially for asp.net zero).
We still want to wait for Razor Pages approach to be more mature and accepted by the community. Then we will have a decision about that.

So, for now, no clear answer :)